# Heroku not launching my spring boot application(has sub modules)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, heroku, procfile

This is my project structure
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RozK9.png)

and i am having trouble launching it on heroku. build works perfectly fine but the application is not launching when i use this proc code:

```
java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -cp scribbler-api/target/classes/:target/dependency/* org.scribbler.api.ScribblerApiApplication
```

it shows this in the logs:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
> 2020-11-18T17:04:49.047929+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.scribbler.api.ScribblerApiApplication.main(ScribblerApiApplication.java:14)
> 2020-11-18T17:04:49.048029+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
> 2020-11-18T17:04:49.048077+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
> 2020-11-18T17:04:49.048194+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
> 2020-11-18T17:04:49.048239+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
> 2020-11-18T17:04:49.048293+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
> 2020-11-18T17:04:49.048331+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 1 more
> 2020-11-18T17:04:49.100850+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
> 2020-11-18T17:04:49.133071+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
> 2020-11-18T17:04:55.780988+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/ui-swagger.html" host=litpoks-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=0daeeb80-91e7-4cd0-b4f
> 4-d0c07d3b963c fwd="119.2.103.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2020-11-18T17:04:56.262194+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=litpoks-blog.herokuapp.com request_id=9c135a8d-a692-487a-9eac-75
> d42a508a0d fwd="119.2.103.156" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

So my main class exists here: inside org.scribbler.api  :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrc0U.png)

the pom file is like this: [pom file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgbmf.png)
and pom file code: `

4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.scribbler</groupId>
<artifactId>scribbler</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>scribbler-api</module>
    <module>scribbler-db</module>
    <module>scribbler-service</module>
</modules>

<packaging>pom</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

`

can you guys tell me what should i do to fix this. do i need to change the procfile? can you guys suggest solutions to this.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @Toerktumlare images are there click on those links

Comment: read what i posted, you should `not` post images of code.

Comment: thanks changed the images having code to code

Comment: post your full pom.xml if it cant find your main class its because you are most likely packaging your jar file in an incorrect way. Also why are you pointing out where the main class is, spring boot builds fat jars. Have you ever run a spring boot application on command line?

Comment: you most likely need to read the https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-first-application getting started section, and especially the part about running the example and creating a executable jar.

Comment: @Toerktumlare ive added the pom file, could you check

Comment: Stop posting images of your code. And if that is your pomfile ofc its not going to work. You need to read up on the wntire basics of how you build a spring boot application, because you have built it like it was a java ee app. Spring boot is not javva ee. I suggest you do a basic getting started tutorial with spring boot so you understand the basics of building a spring boot app. Voting to close, needs more focus, we cant teach you entire spring boot here.